# Using ColorBlendFactor with white/black textures in spritekit

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, cpu-usage, sktilemapnode

I'm making a 2d platformer game for iOS with spritekit. It is mainly a entity/component model.

I use a lot of SKTilemapnodes for my platforms in the game. In these tilemaps I use white/black images for my tiles, so that I can change the colorBlendFactor on them and color to the color that I want.

I'm curious if using this colorBlendfactor cause any issues with cpu usage?

Is there anything I need to consider when using this blendfactor?

Also hard to tell without seeing my project, but what are some best practices maybe for deciding on using a method like this, or creating multiple tile Images of different color instead of using this method...

Thank you for any assistance.

Comment: color blending should happen on the GPU side, so you shouldn't see any hits with the CPU

Comment: @Knight0fDragon, does this not have any adverse affects? I read that it is good to reduce the amount of "opacity" used. I'm assuming "opacity" has the same affect as alpha, and the blend mode is alpha, so I didn't know if this could cause extra processing. Even if on the GPU.

Comment: i always took opacity to be alpha,  was not aware of any difference.  I do not remember everything that goes on behind the scenes, but it adds a little more processing time while saving a lot of memory (if you have a red block and a blue block, you can use a white block + blending)  I am pretty sure it is just matrix math which the GPU should be able to handle with ease.